# Android TextView ellipsize end with unicode emoji

Tags: android, unicode, textview, emoji

I have a list item with a TextView. The TextView can also contain some unicode emoji, but when I say `android:ellipsize="end"` one of the emoji may be cut and there will be a square with a '?'.

How can I prevent cutting unicode codes?

**Here is my layout file:**

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    ... />
```

Comment: instead of using 'end' try using other values like marquee/middle or start

Comment: The Problem is I need the elipsis on the end of the TextView, but the unicode emoji is seen as splittable text from the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It may be help you.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true
```

Comment: Although this solution has no ellipsis, it is also a good way to handle overflow. Thanks!!